# Having trouble getting $in operator to update all documents by array of _id

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my Schema:

```
    var User = new Schema({
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        email: {
            address: String,
            confirmed: Boolean,
            confirm_code: String
        },
        saved_artists: [Schema.ObjectId],
        new_releases: [Schema.ObjectId],
        sync_queue: {
            id: Number,
            status: String
        }
    });
```

and

```
var Artist = new Schema({
    spotify_id: {type: String, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    recent_release: {type: {
        id: String,
        title: String,
        release_date: String,
        images: []
    }, required: true},
    users_tracking: [Schema.ObjectId]
});
```

and here is my update query:

```
User.update({_id: {$in: artist.users_tracking}}, {$addToSet: {'new_releases': artist._id}}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // todo turn into debug report
            console.log(err);
        }
        User.find({}, function (err, users) {
            console.log(users);
        })
    })
```

When I run a unit test, $in only selects the first `_id` of the array and updates that one and ignores any others. The input array looks like this:

`["5993864f44456a1b50378bc3","5993864f44456a1b50378bc4"]`

and if I run the update query iteratively like below, it outputs correctly:

```
for (var i =0; i < artist.users_tracking.length; i++){
        User.update({'_id': artist.users_tracking[i]}, {$addToSet: {'new_releases': artist._id}}, function(err) {

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `User.update()` to `User.updateMany()` provided the expected query output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the [`multi` option to `true`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).

```
User.update({
    _id: { $in: artist.users_tracking }
}, { 
    $addToSet: { new_releases: artist._id }
}, { 
    multi: true 
}, ...)
```